# How to remove .php extension the pro way

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, php-extension

I have created my first Php solution but have trouble removing the .php extension from the URL. It works in the root but not in sub-folders?

Eg `www.domain.com/index.php` reached from `www.domain.com/index` (or `www.domain.com/`)

Then it gets tricky.

For example. `www.domain.com/en/europe/bikes/racer-bike.php` will not differ from `www.domain.com/en/bikes/racer-bike` without ending up on `www.domain.com/en/bikes/ and on index.php`

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,QSA]

# Add trailing slash to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Try it and it works:

My dirs structure

```
/
index.php
/sub
    file.php
```

And my htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^\/]*)$
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([A-Za-z]+)/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/(.*)$ $1/$2.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Try it

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong ... Mostly you do not make php files for each uri (route). You should not remove php extension you should direct all uri's to index.php and use some router to define how to handle each request. or you can just use some framework to do that like laravel or symfony etc.